# What's the easiest way to save Task Manager's Processes tab as a CSV file?

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, task-manager

I want to get the information in the Task Manager's Processes tab into Excel.

I want to do this because I am trying to make an image to deploy to a few workstation and need to see what I should include as running processes at startup, taking memory usage into account.

So is there any way I can extract the data as a CSV or .xls file?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't do this using the task manager itself, but you can use the built-in `tasklist` command line program to do it. Open a command prompt (`cmd.exe`) and use the following commands:

- Type `tasklist` to output a list of all the currently running processes
- To output as a csv, type `tasklist /FO csv`
- To save the output of the command line to a file, add `> filename.csv` to the end of the command; for example, `tasklist /FO csv > "%userprofile%\desktop\tasks.csv"`.

For full documentation on the various options for what to output, type `tasklist /?` into the command prompt.

Comment: Oh nice, `tasklist` totally slipped my mind, and definitely didn't know about csv formatting. I'm going to delete my answer. +1.

Comment: Why thank you, good sir! I might have left your answer though - it's probably not ideal for this exact situation, but other visitors from the internet may still find it useful if they need to export additional details to a spreadhseet, since process explorer gives more information.

Comment: Why "/fo" in capital letters? Documentation only uses lower case. Both work.

Comment: @TheincredibleJan Unlike on *nix, Windows is pretty tolerant with case either way.

Answer (score 2):

### One line in CMD

Replace **`<username>`** to your user name and run in cmd:

```
tasklist /v /FO csv > "C:\Users\<username>\Documents\tasks.csv"
```

---

For more documentation info go here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/tasklist

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).