# How to export Windows Task Manager's Information/Tabs?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, task-manager

Is there a way to export the information contain within the Windows Task Manager? I know how to export the processes tab but I'm more interested on the Users Tab.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/209555/whats-the-easiest-way-to-save-task-managers-processes-tab-as-a-csv-file

Comment: That only exports the processes tab, I want to export the Users Tab. This one displays who is connected to the machine.

Comment: @Moses it is differant not process information but users and sessions opened

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command line to view the list of logged on users:

```
wmic ComputerSystem Get UserName
```

Then you may copy/paste the output, or direct it into a text file, as you wish.